# Why does my boot keep failing after an initial successful install?

Tags: boot, initramfs, fsck, busybox

My machine is an old HP G60. I don't know all the specs but it's powerful enough to run Ubuntu ~19. But the distro doesn't seem to be the issue here.

I've done puppy linux, mint, and now ubuntu. I wipe whatever is on the machine, and install these distros. The first install is always successful; it follows all the steps of any instructional video I've seen.

But within the first 3 times (usually the first) after turning the machine off and back on, I get booted into busybox/initramfs. Also, the issue always seems to be with `/dev/sda5`. I get a message telling me I need to run a manual fsck on it. But I've done that about 100 times.

Sometimes it completes successfully, sometimes not, sometimes nothing happens and the machine boots fine, sometimes it says it is successful but I can't get into my desktop.
Could this be a hardware issue?

Comment: It looks like the HDD is broken.

Comment: Try installing the smartmontools package and run the smartctl on the disk.  Might indicate the problem.

Comment: What are you storing on /dev/sda5?

Comment: @Pilot6 is this something I can troubleshoot or is it just worth it to replace the disk?

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 I'm not storing anything on it, that's what is kind of strange to me. Theoretically everything should be a blank slate.

Comment: Is there a reason you're keeping it around rather than just using the Erase Disk option during the install? Or are you doing manual partitioning and /dev/sda5 is going to eventually be used for something?